# Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Subscriptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, error-handling, stripe-payments, subscription

I've implemented Stripe to handle subscriptions on my website. Everything is working fine except when it comes to cancel a subscription.

This is my Controller:

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

def cancel
 @sub = params[:sub]
 @customer = retrieve_stripe_user
 @subs = @customer.subscriptions.retrieve(@sub).delete
 if @subs.status == "canceled"
  flash[:success] = "Your subscription has been successfully canceled."
 else
  flash[:failure] = "We are having problems. Please try again."
 end
 redirect_to :back
end

def retrieve_stripe_user
 Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_user_id)
end
```

When I try to cancel a subcription 2 things happen:
- I receive this error: **Customer XXX does not have a subscription with ID YYY**
- The Subscription is ACTUALLY deleted from Stripe!

What is even more strange is that when I try do use the same code from the Rails console, everything works properly.

Does anyone know what to do here? I'm a bit lost..

Thanks

Comment: could your code be called twice for some reason? I had that the other day so the first one would delete something and the second one would display an error and leave me confused

Comment: I thought the same, although that is really the only code I have in the controller... where could I have duplicated the code?

Comment: Have you checked your stripe logs? This would confirm if your code did indeed try to cancel twice, or maybe give another clue.

Comment: That's a good one @DavidTaiaroa. I've replicated the error and unfortunately there's no trace in logs of a double deletion... There must be something going on with the API, just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a ruby guy, so go easy on me if I'm off base here ;)

The sample ruby code from https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#cancel_subscription is

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_5SGFGHJOiadMQq")
customer.subscriptions.retrieve("sub_5Swi4bZ4xEyClq").delete
```

Have you confirmed that your code is actually passing in the correct subscription ID?

**Edit**
It's seems very odd to me that when you cancel a subscription you get an error and yet the subscription is actually deleted. When trying to simulate the same conditions (in a php environment) I noticed there's a significant delay ( 60sec + ) between when I cancelled a subscription and when cancellation actually showed in my Stripe dashboard logs, which threw me off at the start. I can't think of anything else to suggest, other than keep looking at the logs and events in the dashboard for clues.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes I take the subscription ID from the variable @sub, which is a string.

Comment: To quote from the stripe docs, 'Stripe sends out customer.subscription.deleted event when a customer’s subscription is canceled immediately.' . Any chance you could be misinterpreting this as a on your web hook @ManuelFrigerio ?

Comment: No because I don't have a webhook. Also, it was working perfectly until yesterday when another controller stopped to work. Can be an issue with Stripe?